# How to get polarised electromagnetic TE wave differential equation from Maxwell's Equations?

Tags: calculus

I wish to understand how the following equation:

$\frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2 E_x}{\partial z^2} + n^2 k_0 E_x = \frac{\text{d} (\ln \mu)}{\text{d}z}\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial z} $

where

$n^2 = \epsilon \mu$

and

$k_0 = \frac{\omega}{c} = \frac{2 \pi}{\lambda_0}$

is obtained from the following six equations:

1a. $\frac{\partial H_z}{ \partial y} - \frac{\partial Hy}{\partial z} + \frac{i \epsilon \omega}{c}E_x = 0$

1b. $\frac{\partial H_x}{ \partial z} - \frac{\partial H_z}{\partial x} = 0$

1c. $\frac{\partial H_y}{ \partial x} - \frac{\partial H_x}{\partial y} = 0$

2a. $\frac{i \omega \mu}{c}H_x = 0$

2b. $\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial z} - \frac{i \omega \mu}{c} H_y = 0$

2c. $\frac{\partial E_x}{\partial y} + \frac{i \omega \mu}{c} H_z = 0$

The six equations are obtained from Maxwells equations for a time harmonic transverse electric wave (a linearly polarised time harmonic electromagnetic wave propogated through a stratified medium), incidenting on the y-z plane. In this case $E_y = Ez = 0$, and there is a time dependence of $\exp{(-i \omega t)}$.

My textbook of choice (Born, Principles of Optics) states that the first equation can be obtained by eliminating $H_y$ and $H_z$ between (1a), (2b) and (2c), but I can't replicate this, and would like to know the exact steps.

Comment: Which quantities can be assumed to be constant here?

Comment: $\omega$, $\mu$, $\epsilon$ and $c$ are constants

Comment: It's simple, I think: differentiate (2b) and (2c) with respect to $z$ and $y$ respectively, then substitute the resulting partial derivatives into (1a).

Comment: Wait: Based on that first equation, the permeability $\mu$ is certainly not constant.

Comment: Well, $\mu$ is a property of a material, and for some materials it is approximately constant, and others, a function of $H$. I'm happy just to consider the first case, constant $\mu$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15943/discussion-between-semiclassical-and-crobar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me get you started by first assuming $\mu$ to be constant as stated in comments. We take partial derivatives with respect to $z$ and $y$ respectively of the last two equations, and solve for the partials of $H_y,H_z$:
$$ \partial_z H_y=\frac{ic}{\mu\omega}\partial_z^2E_x, \hspace{8mm}
\partial_z H_y=-\frac{ic}{\mu\omega}\partial_y^2E_x $$
Applying these in the first equation implies that 
$$ \frac{i\epsilon\omega}{c}E_x = \partial_z H_y - \partial_y H_z
= \frac{i c}{\mu \omega}\left(\partial_y^2E_x+\partial_z^2E_x\right)\\
\implies \partial_y^2E_x+\partial_z^2E_x-\epsilon\mu\frac{\omega^2}{c^2}=0$$
which can be seen to match the LHS of your first equation upon checking definitions. Note that  the RHS vanishes---as of course it must, since we proceeded under the assumption that $\mu$ was constant! That means that one must repeat things with $\mu=\mu(z)$ in order to obtain the permeability gradient on the RHS.

Comment: Yes, and you are right that $\mu$ could change, e.g. as you travel through a region, which was my problem.

Comment: That's presumably the polarization bit (I should remember, but it's been a whle since I did this bit of electromagnetism)